# Searching for gtk widget

Tags: widget, gtk

Is there any special widget in gtk+ that shows a set of tabs below the menu bar and has default "X" closing button (like in gedit). If there isn't, how to create one or where can I find it (in what other window library?)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GtkNotebook` and pack a small close button in with each tab label.

When in doubt, if you want to create something "like in Gedit", then look at the Gedit source code: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree

Comment: I packed button and label into hbox, placed this into a tab and it worked. Thanks for help. One more question - what mechanisms are used in gedit code to create non-default widgets. Is it as hard as it semms? – vanquard just now edit

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I would just like to know what mysterious force stands behind creation of various elements of gedit ^^, like for example the closing button in the tabs, which would be very useful for me and I would appreciate it to be build-in widget in gtk but is isn't and I don't know how to create it. Would it be hard for me as a beginner because I don't know if the work I would have to put into it is worth the final effect?

Comment: This is called a "custom widget", and the complexity depends on the language used and the complexity of the widget itself. You'll find some tutorials on the internet by searching "custom widget gtk".